# Git com Github / Projeto Java

Tags: java, git, eclipse, github

Olá

Gostaria de uma ajuda, por exemplo, criei um projeto no Eclipse e quero subir o mesmo no Github, existe um arquivo .gitignore e esse arquivo é criado automaticamente ignorando o diretório /src/ do meu projeto, alguém sabe onde configuro essa criação? Como você pode observar no anexo eu possuo alguns diretórios e arquivos que já estão no Github, gostaria de saber os que eu não preciso subir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Atenciosamente,

Diego

Comment: Dê uma buscada por exemplos de .gitignore que ignoram arquivos de múltiplos IDEs, como Eclipse, Netbeans, IntelliJ IDEA...

Answer (score 3):

Bom, você pode alterar o seu .gitignore como desejar, acho estranho ele ser criado automaticamente ignorando o sua /src/. Mas você pode abrir e tirar qualquer coisa lá de dentro. O ideal é você subir apenas o essencial para o github, por exemplo, código fonte, arquivos de configuração, arquivos de CI, pom.xml, etc.. Tudo o que facilite quem for usar seu repositório. O que não se sobe, são as depencias do projeto. Pq quem for clonar , vai instalar as depencias a partir do maven.